# angularjs facebook-login fetch user data

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-login

I am working on angularjs and create login with facebook using https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook module. But now I'm unable to fetch user data after login:
**My controller is:**

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function () {
  var promise = authenticationServices.fbLogin();
  promise.then(
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    function(error){
       utilityServices.showToast('error', 'Unable to connect with facebook');
     });
};
```

**My services is:**

```
this.fbLogin = function() {
        $('.btn-disable').addClass('disabled');
        Facebook.login(function(response) {
            if(response.status === "connected") {
                console.log(response.authResponse);
                Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
                        if(!response || response.error) {
                            deferred.reject('Error occured');
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }
                    }
                );
            } else {
                $('.btn-disable').removeClass('disabled');
            }
        },{
            auth_type: 'rerequest',
            scope: 'user_likes, email, user_friends'
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Now i want to fetch user data as I set in scope but i only get id and name as show in image below: The app access the follwing permission but data doesnt available 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the fields now:

```
Facebook.api('/me?fields=email,name,id', ...
```

For getting the likes, there is another endpoint: `/me/likes`

...or you can add it in the fields parameter too:

```
Facebook.api('/me?fields=email,name,id,likes', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-
urlencoded';

    $cordovaOauth.facebook(" devlper id ", ["email", "public_profile"]).then(function(result) {
         displayData($http, result.access_token);
        var name = result.data.name;
                var gender = result.data.gender;
             var location = result.data.location;
                var picture = result.data.picture;

    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    };
     function displayData($http, access_token)
            {
                $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {params: {access_token: access_token, fields: "name,gender,location,picture,email", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) 
                        {

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    var name = result.data.name;
                    var gender = result.data.gender;
                    var location = result.data.location;
                    var picture = result.data.picture;
                    var id =result.data.id;
                    var userid=id;


                }, function(error) {
                    alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
                    console.log(error);
                });
```